# ngBootstrap Capture click event on typeahead suggestions

Tags: css, angular6, ng-bootstrap

when I type **'ala'** it displays 2 states in suggestions '**alabama**' and '**alaska**'. Now what I need is as soon as I click on 'alaska'/'alabama' any item in list it should call my method

```
methodAbc(){
   //Some complex logic
   alert("Method called.");
}
```

Sample code link [click here](https://stackblitz.com/angular/rkjqryvgvxk)

I tried blur, focus, etc events on text box they didnt work way I need. Click do not triggers on item selection it triggers when I click inside text box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use the `selectItem` event from ng-bootstrap's [ngbTypeAhead API](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/api#NgbTypeaheadSelectItemEvent)

```
<input id="typeahead-template" type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="model" 
   [ngbTypeahead]="search" [resultTemplate]="rt" [inputFormatter]="formatter"
   (selectItem)="methodABC($event)" />
```

See [updated sample code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bqhqg3)

Comment: Awesome sir. Thank you very much